# 本番環境と開発環境で読み込む js を使い分ける方法は？

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

rails 3.2 を使っています。

development モードの時は

```
app/assets/javascripts/ajaxzip3.js
```

を

production モードの時は

```
app/assets/javascripts/ajaxzip3-https.js
```

を使う。という事は可能でしょうか？

[ajaxzip3 という郵便番号検索ライブラリ](https://code.google.com/p/ajaxzip3/)を使用しているのですが
production 環境の時は https で、development 環境の時は http で使っているためです。

上記のリンクサイトには以下の記述があります。本番環境のみ動作させるのは簡単ですが、やっぱり開発環境でも動いてくれないと楽しく無いです (^^;

```
# httpサーバの場合はhttp://ajaxzip3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ajaxzip3/ajaxzip3.js をご利用ください。
# httpsサーバの場合はhttps://ajaxzip3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ajaxzip3/ajaxzip3-https.js をご利用ください。
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
先ほど気づいたのですが、大ボケかましてたようです。(お恥ずかしい...)
当方、「常に https な js を使えば良い」で問題解決できました。

https → http はNGですが、
http → https はOK なのでうまく行きました。

ともあれ、質問自体の意味としては間違っていないと思うので、これは
これで良さそうですが...
(Rails.env.production? や request.protocol で判断するという意味で)

Answer (score 2):

`request.protocol`とHelperメソッドを組み合わせるとスッキリ書けそうです。

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def ajaxzip3_include_tag
    file_name = ssl? ? 'ajaxzip3-https.js' : 'ajaxzip3.js'
    javascript_include_tag(file_name)
  end

  def ssl?
    request.protocol == 'https://'
  end
end
```

```
<% # app/views/layouts/application.html.erb %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Your app name</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <%= ajaxzip3_include_tag %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

あと、productionで使うなら `config.assets.precompile` でファイルを指定しておく必要があるかもしれません。

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.assets.precompile += %w(ajaxzip3-https.js)
```

参考になれば幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

`app/views` 内のHTMLで以下のように書くのはどうでしょう。

```
<% if Rails.env.production? %>
  <script src="https://ajaxzip3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ajaxzip3/ajaxzip3-https.js"></script>
<% else %>
  <script src="http://ajaxzip3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ajaxzip3/ajaxzip3.js"></script>
<% end %>
```

Slim の場合はこんな感じでしょうか。

```
- if Rails.env.production?
  script src="https://ajaxzip3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ajaxzip3/ajaxzip3-https.js"
- else
  script src="http://ajaxzip3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ajaxzip3/ajaxzip3.js"
```